# Passing a complex object across cross domain

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am working with two web applications, one is webform-based Site1 and other is an MVC application Site2.

**TODO:**

Pass a complex object from Site1 to Site2. In response get View from Site2 to Site1 and display it:

```
       function test()
    {       
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 url: '../Chart/Mypage.aspx/GetInformation',
                async: false,
                success: function (response) {                    
                    alert(response.d);
                    var authHeader = window.btoa("Ankita:Ankita");
                    var r = {"Id":50345520,"FirstName":"Matthew","LastName":"McCauley","MiddleName":"","Suffix":null,"NPI":"1083043491","Address":"614 Esplanade St.","City":"Piscataway","State":"NJ","ZIP":"08854","Country":"United States","SubscriberFirstName":null,"SubscriberLastName":null,"SubscriberMiddleName":null,"SubscriberSSN":null,"SubscriberDOB":null,"SubscriberGender":null,"SubscriberSuffix":null,"SubscriberAddress":null,"SubscriberCity":null,"SubscriberState":null,"SubscriberZIP":null,"SubscriberCountry":null,"VisitDate":"null"}"
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        url: 'http://localhost:52099/Controller/Index',
                        data: r,                            
                         headers: { Authorization: authHeader},                         
                        dataType: 'jsonp',   
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert("done");
                            // $("#popupdivmodal").find('div.body').html('').html(response);
                            callFunction(response);
                        },
                        error: function(e){
                            alert(e);
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        return false;
    }
    function callFunction(data){
        $('#popupdivmodal').html(data.message);
    }

<asp:Button ID="Scriptbtn" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="SureScript" OnClientClick="test();"></asp:Button>
```

**At Controller side**

```
        [HttpGet]
        [BasicAuthentication("Ankita", "Ankita", BasicRealm = "Test")]
        public ActionResult Index([System.Web.Http.FromUri]ClientInformation client)
        {               
            return new JsonpResult(new { message = this.RenderRazorViewToString("Index", client) });               
        }

  public class JsonpResult : ActionResult
{
    private readonly object _obj;

    public JsonpResult(object obj)
    {
        _obj = obj;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var callbackname = context.HttpContext.Request["callback"];
        var jsonp = string.Format("{0}({1})", callbackname, serializer.Serialize(_obj));
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = "application/json";
        response.Write(jsonp);
    }
}

public static class RazorViewToString
{

    public static string RenderRazorViewToString(this Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
    {

        controller.ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

By doing this I am getting a client object to the MVC app but via querystring. Is there any other way to achieve this, as querystring has its own limitation for length?

Comment: Is there a reason this is using JSONP, and not something more secure and thought out, like using a CORS request?

Comment: See https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ for a rundown on CORS